# having private variable vector of itself

Tags: c++

I just wonder if I can do something like this:

```
class apple
{
public: "constructor and public method in here"
private:
  vector<*apple> allApple;
}
```

is this code okay?

Comment: If it compiles and always runs as expected, it's OK. Have you tried compiling it?

Comment: Also look up how pointers are declared. You're using the asterisk and the typename in the wrong order.

Comment: this is not okay, it is `apple *` not `* apple`. The templated type you are trying to achieve is 'pointer to apple' where the star comes after the type name.

Comment: don't have any computer w/ c++ around. :)

Comment: @RudiAksam are you kidding ? http://ideone.com/ is around, all the time ;)

Comment: @SirDarius thx man, I don't know about that site. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean a vector of pointers to the same type,

```
vector<apple*> allApple;
```

in which case, yes, you can, although you might prefer to keep [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) if these are to point to dynamically allocated objects.

Comment: is there any particular reason why do you think smart pointers is better than vector?

Comment: @RudiAksam smart pointers are better than raw pointers, if they point to dynamically allocated objects. But you keep the vector. Just a vector of smart pointers.

Comment: @juanchopanza Smart pointers aren't in general better than raw pointers; they're just different.  In this case, it depends on what the vector is used for.  If it's for navigation, raw pointers are the most appropriate solution.  (Regretfully, not only does the OP not tell us what he's trying to do, he's chosen arbitrary enough names that we can't guess.  Or at least, _I_ can't imagine anything named `Apple` which would contain a vector of pointers to other apples, be it for navigation or for any other reason.)